# Angular2: EventEmitter based service too many calls

Tags: angular, eventemitter

So I have an EventEmitter service that I want to use in order to share data between components, here is the code

```js
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ObservableService {
    data = [];
    eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    setSharedData(key, value) {
        this.data[key] = value;
        this.eventEmitter.emit(this.data);
    }

    getSharedData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

And here is how I want to use it

```js
 ngOnInit() {
        this._observable.eventEmitter.subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('working');
            this.filter.emit(data);
        })
    }
```

So, everything works perfect except one thing - console log showing `working` sign 13 times!

Where this strange behavior goes from?

Comment: `EventEmitter` is not supposed to be used in services. `EventEmitter` is for `@Output()` only. Just use a `Subject`. This won't change anything with your problem. To your problem. Just don't call `setSharedData` more often than you want the event be emitted.

Comment: I guess you are calling `setSharedData` directly or indirectly from a binding in a components template which is invoked every time Angular runs change detection, but this part is missing in your question and therefore it's hard to give advice. In general don't call functions in bindings.

Comment: Actually yes, I'm calling `setSharedData` like so `(change)="onChange($event)"`, is there any way to work around it?

Comment: Calling methods for events is fine, just not from value bindings like `[prop]="calcMe()"` or `<div>{{calcMe()}}</div>`. If you call it only from that event handler means, that the event does happen that often.

Comment: Actually I have a `select` html input and I want to send data to service each time it changed, how is it possible without value bindings like `[prop]="calcMe()"`?

Comment: I didn't say that you can or should do this. I'm just making assumptions because your question doesn't contain any information about how or when `setSharedData` is called so often. All I can derive from your question is, that it is called more often that you expect it to be called.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EventEmitter` are used to raise custom events from directive or component. Its not advisable to use it inside `service` as you have used.

You should use `Observable` inside your service so that you can `subscribe` for it inside your `Component`.

Check [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) to know how to use `Observable`.

Answer (score -2):

EventEmitter do not function. 
I think you should use @Output with EventEmitter:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
@Component({
selector: 'sector'
})
export class ObservableService {
    data = [];
    @Output eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    setSharedData(key, value) {
        this.data[key] = value;
        this.eventEmitter.emit(this.data);
    }

    getSharedData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

and HTML

```
   <sector (eventEmitter)="_eventEmitter" ></sector>
```

component

```
 _eventEmitter: any;
 ngOnInit() {
        this.filter = this._eventEmitter;
    }
```